# How do I get the IP of VMs NIC?

Tags: java, automation, sdk, vsphere

I am using the VSPHERE JDK JAVA 6.5. Where are the IPs of a VM hidden? I got the vmNics() with some infos, but the IPs are not a part of this.

Which class I have to use?
Thx

```
VMTypes.Info vmInfo = vcVAPIConnect.getVM(vapiStub, vmID);
if (vmInfo != null) {
    System.out.println("VM Detail Id   = " + vmID);
    System.out.println("VM Detail Name = " + vmInfo.getName());

    Set<String> fldList = vmInfo._getDynamicFieldNames();
    System.out.println("VM Dyn. Fieldlist (Size): " + fldList.size());
    for (String fldValue: fldList) {
        System.out.println("VM Detail Name = " + fldValue + " / " + vmInfo._getDynamicField(fldValue));
    }

    System.out.println("VM Detail Hardware Version   = " + vmInfo.getHardware().getVersion());

    System.out.println("VM Detail CPU CoresPerSocket = " + vmInfo.getCpu().getCoresPerSocket());
    System.out.println("VM Detail CPU Count          = " + vmInfo.getCpu().getCount());
    System.out.println("VM Detail CPU CannonialName  = " + vmInfo.getCpu()._getCanonicalName());

    System.out.println("VM Detail RAM Size           = " + vmInfo.getMemory().getSizeMiB());
    System.out.println("VM Detail RAM CannonialName  = " + vmInfo.getMemory()._getCanonicalName());

    Map<String, EthernetTypes.Info> vmNics = vmInfo.getNics();
    System.out.println("VM Detail NIC Size           = " + vmNics.size());
    for (String nicKey: vmNics.keySet()) {
        System.out.println("VM Detail NIC Key            = " + nicKey);
        System.out.println("VM Detail NIC CannonialName  = " + vmNics.get(nicKey)._getCanonicalName());
        System.out.println("VM Detail NIC MacAddr        = " + vmNics.get(nicKey).getMacAddress());
        System.out.println("VM Detail NIC MacType        = " + vmNics.get(nicKey).getMacType().toString());
        System.out.println("VM Detail NIC Label          = " + vmNics.get(nicKey).getLabel());
        System.out.println("VM Detail NIC PCI Slot       = " + vmNics.get(nicKey).getPciSlotNumber());
        System.out.println("VM Detail NIC Backing Name   = " + vmNics.get(nicKey).getBacking().getNetworkName());
        System.out.println("VM Detail NIC Backing Net    = " + vmNics.get(nicKey).getBacking().getNetwork());
        System.out.println("VM Detail NIC Backing Host   = " + vmNics.get(nicKey).getBacking().getHostDevice());

        fldList = vmNics.get(nicKey)._getDynamicFieldNames();
        System.out.println("VM Detail NIC Dyn. Fieldlist (Size):    " + fldList.size());
        for (String fldValue: fldList) {
            System.out.println("VM Detail NIC = " + fldValue + " / " + vmInfo._getDynamicField(fldValue));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show your code.

Answer (score 1):

The IP address information is located in a different service, separate from the NIC information. This is because the IP address is being pulled from the guest OS through VMware Tools.

The service is called Guest (after Guest Operations) and the IP Address, amongst other properties, can be found there: https://code.vmware.com/apis/366/vsphere-automation/VMware-vSphere-Automation-SDK-REST-6.7.0/docs/apidocs/operations/com/vmware/vcenter/vm/guest/identity.get-operation.html

One issue worth noting, I'm not positive when this service was presented. I know it was not in the release of vSphere 6.5, but it may have been added at some point down the road. I do know it is in vSphere 6.7, but that is probably not helpful since you're using the 6.5 SDK.

Comment: I solved it by using the Power CLI and Powershell from a Linux System.

Comment: I found that the "net" property of "guest" attribute of the virtual machine object (OP's post has it as "vmInfo") also has "IP address". This way, all the NIC's IP addresses can be listed.